# Exploitation of Equality in Inequality.

Tags: inequality, summation, proof-explanation

I want to ask: 
How do I exploit equalities in the solution of an inequality when equality holds for variables equal to each other?
One can take this example:

> For positive real numbers that sum to $3$, prove that$$\sqrt{a + \sqrt{b^2 + c^2}} + 
> \sqrt{b + \sqrt{c^2 + a^2}} + 
> \sqrt{c + \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \ge
> 3\sqrt{\sqrt{2} + 1}$$

As this one which is a little tough for me, one can almost easily say that (though I am not so sure)

> Equality holds for $a=b=c=1$.

But how do I exploit this in the solution? So far, I have squared both sides, but ended up only with a giant square root term, and still I can not see what can I do with this equality case.

This is not only for this one, but every time I solve an inequality and in the solution see that the equality holds for variables equal to each other, I can't still observe what happened in my solution from this equality.

Any explanation will be thankfully welcome!

Comment: Can you provide a link or source for this problem?

Comment: @TeresaLisbon It is from Secrets in Inequalities

Comment: I didn't get it; what has minima and maxima to do with equality case? Actually I don't need a solution. I have it. I wanted to know an answer to the question at the beginning of my post.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Yes, but see please that that helps solve a problem (if not this one).

Comment: I had a look at the answer below while writing mine, and it looks good. But I still want to say this : there are far too many situations where the phenomena you talk about is exhibited. You can't make out at a glance if something will work or not, because there are too many inequalities, which are equalities if everything is equal (Special case of CS, AM-GM, Generalized mean inequalities, Jensen's inequality for the strict case etc.) so you will have to experiment and find what is working and what fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step does not change something:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+2\sqrt{(a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2})(b+\sqrt{a^2+c^2})}\right)\geq9\sqrt2+9$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+2\sqrt{(a+\sqrt{b^2+c^2})(b+\sqrt{a^2+c^2})}\right)\geq9\sqrt2+6.$$
The second step:

By C-S $$\sqrt{b^2+c^2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\sqrt{(1^2+1^2)(b^2+c^2)}\geq\frac{b+c}{\sqrt2}$$ saves the case of the equality occurring: $a=b=c=1$.

It's enough to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+2\sqrt{\left(a+\frac{b+c}{\sqrt2}\right)\left(b+\frac{a+c}{\sqrt2}\right)}\right)\geq9\sqrt2+6.$$
The rest is the same: any step saves the case of the equality occurring, which gives the proof.

Comment: I think that the constants $9$ and $6$ in the first $2$ expressions are interchanged.

Comment: @Book Of Flames It was typo. I fixed. See now.

Comment: How does in general the case wherein equality holds for $a=b=c$ helps in solving 
**any** inequality?

Comment: @Book Of Flames It's the first think about which we need to think, when we look for the solution: we need to save the case of the equality occurring. Also, we did not make something with the first $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ because otherwise,  we would be get a wrong inequality.

Comment: But the same applies there: $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2} \ge \frac{a + b}{\sqrt{2}}$, that is - same equality case, then why would it give wrong inequality?

Comment: @Book Of Flames  Yes, of course, but it gives a wrong inequality and we did not use C-S for this expression.

Comment: Where does it go wrong --- and how did you know it?

Comment: @Book Of Flames I don't know it before, but I checked that it leads to the wrong inequality.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Thanks. But is there a specific advantage in the equality case $a=b=c=1$?

Comment: @Book Of Flames  There is possibility to use C-S, AM-GM and more and more.

Comment: Okay. Thank you sir!

Comment: Do you have nice links for learning UVW method and Buffalo way?

Comment: And for Bacteria method. Those are only which I have heard in names, but do not have any idea about them.

Comment: About $uvw$ see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791 There is also my paper in Russian. About BW see here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h522084 About Bacteria see my posts. I have no an useful link.

Comment: Thanks! I think that they are helpful; at least in some hard problems Buffalo way works fine, in my opinion.

Comment: I am sorry to interrupt you again, but I just wanted to ask that are Vasile's Books enough for inequalities asked at olympiads like IMO?

Comment: @Book Of Flames  Yes, I think so.